# How to reference an anonymous JavaScript function?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a Page Method using a jQuery 'attached' event function, in which I like to use the closure to keep the event target local, as below, but page method calls declare several 'error' functions, and I would like to use one function for all of them.  If, in the below code, I was handling an error and not success, how could I use my single, anonymous handler for all 3 error functions?

```
        $(":button").click(function () {
            var button = this;
            PageMethods.DoIt(
                function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(button);
                });
        });
```

This example passes an anonymous function for the success callback.  There is only one of these.  If I was passing an error callback, how could I use 'function (e, c, t)' for all 3 error callbacks?

ADDED:  What I would like to do here is trigger an AJAX call whenever the user clicks a toggle button (checkbox), but to improve responsiveness, I want to toggle the button state immediately, and only 'untoggle' it if the AJAX call fails.

Now, in my client-side `click()` event handler, I would like to use anonymous functions inside the scope of `click()' so that the functions have access to the`this`event argument, but I don't want to 'declare' three functions for the`onTimeout`,`onError`, and 'onAbort` arguments of the PageMethods.MyFunction function.  if I declare a named function outside of the click handler, it no longer has access to the 'this' parameter of the `click()` event handler.

Comment: it's not really clear what you're trying to do. explain yourself better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can put a variable with name in front of it, like this:

`var myFunction = function(a, b, c) { ...`

It's been a while I haven't done this but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to keep this function out of global scope, use [the module pattern](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/):

```
(function() {
  function asplode() {
    alert('Your head asplode.');
  }

  $('body').click(asplode);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign an anonymous function to a variable using `var` (always use `var`, otherwise a variable gets global scope, which may cause unexpected results (e.g., *never* declare variable `i` globally)). That's the only way to reference it:

```
var myFunction = function (a, b, c) {
    /* tum de dum */
};  // don't forget this semicolon
```

Then you can use this function in different places:

```
$(":button").click(myFunction);
/* don't put braces after the function name when referencing it,
   else it will be called immediately */
```

You can find more information about function expressions and function declarations in the article [Named function expressions demystified](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The *whole point* of an *anonymous* function is that it has *no name* and thus *cannot be referenced*. (In fact, "anonymous" is basically the Greek word for "unnamed".)

If you want to reference it, you need to give it a name.

Comment: I can argue whether the function gets a name in a function expression (like in SK's and my examples) or not. Those are *still* anonymous functions, assigned to variables. Using the variables, you can reference and call them.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: If you assign it to a name (i.e. a variable), it's no longer anonymous.

Comment: No, it's remains anonymous. What you see in e.g. Firebug is a parsed name. Please read http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/#names-in-debuggers about Firebug showing `(?)()` in the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

From inside the anonymous function, you can reference it as `arguments.callee` (this is how anonymous recursion is achieved).

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think this answers the (ambiguous) question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you may be able to accomplish it like this:

```
    function handler(a, b, c) {
        alert(this); // button
    }

    $(":button").click(function () {
        var button = this;
        PageMethods.DoIt(function () {
            handler.call(button, a, b, c);
        });
    });
```